# change owl carousel 2.0.0 items after ajax call? (reinitialize)

Tags: jquery, ajax, owl-carousel-2

I have thumbnail pictures of projects that is loaded dynamically on click.

This is the jQuery I have:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/project/show/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, id: id},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
        $('.single-project-heading').text(data[0].title);
        $('.single-project-description').text(data[0].description);
        var projectpictures = '';
        $.each(data[1],function(index,value){
            projectpictures += '<div>' +
                '<a href=\"/' + value.path + '\" data-lightbox=\"' + value.project_id + '\">' +
                '<img class=\"small_thumb\" src=\"/' + value.path + '\">' +
                '</a>';
        });
        owl.html(projectpictures);
        owl.data('owlCarousel').reinit({
            pagination: true,
            items: 5,
            rtl: true
        });
    }
});
```

- How can I reinitialize the owl carousel after the AJAX call?
- Or is there a better way of doing this?

I tried the docs but they didn't help me. The docs says to use `reinit` but it says there isn't any `reinit`.

Comment: Have you tried `owl.owlCarousel();` right before the line with the `reinit`?

Comment: @radscheit Yep Unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Is there a link you can share with us? Or a concrete error message?

Comment: @radscheit well it says `TypeError: owl.data(...) is undefined` in console.